# Выборка данных из трех таблиц SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть 3 таблицы идентичной структуры

```
t1                    |   t2                  |     t3   
barcode    barcode    |   barcode    name     |     barcode    name
123        test       |   111        test4    |     222        test3
321        test2      |   123        test     |     321        test2
```

У них у всех уникальный баркод, мне надо получить выборку из всех 3 , так чтобы значения не повторялись
В результате хочу получить

```
barcode        name
123            test    
321            test2   
111            test4
222            test3
```

написал такой запрос на объединение двух ( не уверен что правильно).

```
(SELECT p.barcode, p.name
FROM public.t1 p
LEFT OUTER JOIN  public.t2 ps ON ps.barcode = p.barcode
WHERE ps.barcode is NULL)
UNION ALL
(SELECT p.barcode, p.name
FROM public.t1 p
RIGHT OUTER JOIN public.t2 ps ON ps.barcode = p.barcode
WHERE p.barcode is NULL)
```

Как написать запрос для объединения трех таблиц в выборке

Comment: Если при равном barcode разные name - что делать? Если считать их разными (либо такого не должно случаться) - то вам нужен банальный union без всяких мудрствований. (не union all)

Comment: @Мелкий *либо такого не должно случаться* А что запретит?

Comment: @Akina, ничто, конечно. Но это может банально не волновать автора вопроса

Comment: @Мелкий ну да... в крайнем случае ещё раз придёт, с новым вопросом.

Comment: @Мелкий если встречаются разные имена с 1 баркодом нужно оставить 1(любой не важно из какой таблице )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

операция `UNION ALL` оставит повторы. используйте обычный `UNION`.  Не ясно как в вашем примере фигурируют 2 таблицы, ибо имена `from` совпадают.

*зы: пока писал ответа автор перелопатил вопрос*

```
    SELECT code, name FROM t1
    UNION 
    SELECT code, name FROM t2
    UNION
    SELECT code, name FROM t3
```

данный запрос вернет уникальные пары `code, name`. Если надо получить уникальные `code` и какой-нибдуь `name` к ним, то оберните все это в подзапрос и сделайте группировку, например, с `min`

```
 SELECT code, min(name) as name
 FROM (
      ....
 ) as t
 GROUP BY code
```

возможно, в таком случаем можно вернуть `union all`, или по крайней мере проверить вопрос эффективности так и так. Хотя если данных мало, то смысла нет.